# JunitParams 1.0.6 initializationError

Tags: selenium, junitparams

I have tests which have been running fine with JunitParams 1.0.5, after I upgraded to JunitParams 1.0.6, then got initializationError. Can anyone help with this?

Selenium: 3.3.1
JunitParams: 1.0.6
Firefox: 52ESR

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateFields(Ljava/util/List;)V from class junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.collectInitializationErrors(JUnitParamsRunner.java:405)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:336)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:56)
    at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.<init>(JUnitParamsRunner.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: That looks like a JUnitParams bug. Have you checked their github issues? Looks like a few similar problems there: https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/issues

Comment: Thanks Mark. It works now after I updated to JUnit 4.12. I also updated the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JUnit version compatibility issue. See https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/issues/102 for a similar case.

JUnitParams 1.0.6 requires JUnit 4.12. Make sure you are not overriding this version in your project. If you have JUnit 4.10 or older on your classpath, the `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateFields` method has `private` access modifier. The code that calls it expects it to be `protected` which is the case for JUnit 4.11+. With older JUnit versions you get the error that you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You are right, the parent project is overriding with an older version. It works now after I updated to JUnit 4.12.

Comment: @Jingjing Glad to help. If this solved your problem, you can mark the answer as accepted using the big tick to the left.